# ITunes doesn't play movie with Dell U2713H display because of hdcp

Tags: mac, itunes, mac-mini, hdcp

I have Dell U2713H display connected to mac mini(late 2012) with mini display port to display port cable. When I try to watch Brave by Pixar it gives "This movie can only be played by displays that support HDCP(high bandwidth digital content protection)" error.

What I read from web that this is an issue for old displays with VGA connection. This display is high-end and the connection is display-port so this shouldn't happen. I tried shift+control+option+power button [trick](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19707238#19707238) to reset System management controller but it just restarts the mac. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

ITunes played the movie when I plugged the display to Windows 8 PC with display-port to display-port cable. This means either ITunes on Windows doesn't enforce drm, which is unlikely, or mini display-port output of mac mini(or the cable) doesn't support hdcp.

Comment: are you using any screen sharing tools such as remote desktop or vlc?  That could be causing your problems.  https://discussions.apple.com/message/25116629#25116629

Comment: No I am not using any screen sharing tool or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Dell documentation](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=225-4148) on their website for the Dell U2713H
specifies in the "Tech Specs" section :

> **CONNECTIVITY**
>
> *1 Dual Link Digital Visual Interface connectors (DVI-DL) **with HDCP***
>   1 DisplayPort 1.2 (DP)
>   1 Mini DisplayPort 1.2 (mDP)
>   1 High Definition Multimedia Interface (HDMI)
>   1 DisplayPort out

As it seems that the DisplayPort is out as regarding HDCP, you then have the wrong cable.
HDCP is supported on the Dell U2713H only via DVI-DL.

You should get an `Apple Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI cable`, which does support DHCP
[according to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3382#9).
There are quite a lot of them around, for example [on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_39?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=apple%20mini%20displayport%20to%20dual-link%20dvi%20adapter&sprefix=Apple%20Mini%20DisplayPort%20to%20Dual-Link%20DVI,aps,392).

Comment: I saw the specification and I thought they forget to write it for dp. It baffles me that the display supports hdcp for older technology but not for new one. Why would one interface support hdcp but other doesn't? I think there should be a software or hardware hdcp decoder that takes all digital input from all digital interfaces and decodes it. I will not buy cable and go back to older tech just to watch video and I will not buy any movie from itunes anymore. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: As I don't have access to your hardware there is always the slim possibility that that fault is with your Mini DisplayPort not supporting HDCP for some reason, so that no cable can help. All you can do to verify that, is to ensure that OSX and iTunes are up-to-date, and maybe loan from someone a Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI cable for a final verification. As the chances are that it's the fault of the firmware on the Dell monitor having implemented HDCP only for DVI-DL, you could also try Dell Support - they might have a firmware upgrade (although no trace of it on their website).

Answer (score 1):

The monitor you use supports HDCP, so that shouldn't be a problem. Are you sure you are using a DVI-D cable instead of a DVI-I cable? A DVI-I cable provides an analog signal, which might be causing your problems.

[image]

Comment: I am not using DVI cable. I am using (mini display-port to display-port) cable that came with the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

All available datasheets for this monitor explicitly list HDCP next to DVI and nowhere else.

Content protection/encryption is an optional part of the DisplayPort standard. HDCP over DisplayPort is an option to this option. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The web page for the monitor suggest that HDCP is only supported on the DVI-DP connector.   However I'd try the HDMI connector if possible.  HDCP is more likely to be supported on HDMI than DP.  HDCP is only optionally supported on DP, but is generally included on most HDMI connections. (wikipedia)